# Поиск похожих товаров

Tags: php, mysql

Задача: вывести из бд 4 самых схожих по названию товара. То есть вывести 4 товара, у которых в названиях наибольшее количество общих слов.

Работаю с PHP+Mysql.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `goods` WHERE MATCH (title, content) AGAINST ($search_phrase) LIMIT 0, 4;
-- Powered by MyISAM
```